# How to map multipolygons from a json file that has multiple attributes in Python

Tags: python, geometry, openstreetmap

Hey I want to map all districts of Berlin and found a json file that contains all GPS Data as Multipolygons. Now I am struggling with plotting these datas on a map.

[image: This is how my raw data from my json file looks like]

[image: the picture below belongs to the first picture above]

I managed to read them and created a table with the json data. But I cannot work with this format.

```
charlottenburg = BerlinMap[(BerlinMap['id'] == 404538)]
charlottenburg
```

[image]
    print(charlottenburg.geometry['coordinates'].contains((52.51141, 13.30211)))

But I only get this Error:

> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> >     last)  in 
> >     ----> 1 print(charlottenburg.geometry['coordinates'].contains((52.51141,
> >     13.30211)))
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py
>   in **getitem**(self, key)    1069         key =
>   com.apply_if_callable(key, self)    1070         try:
>   -> 1071             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)    1072     1073             if not is_scalar(result):
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
>   in get_value(self, series, key)    4728         k =
>   self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")    4729         try:
>   -> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))    4731         except KeyError
>   as e1:    4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer()
>   or self.is_boolean()):
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()
>
> KeyError: 'coordinates'

What I want is to create something like **this**:
https://gist.github.com/chaudum/e8097ab9873ec71666b2

Comment: Python accept JSON, so you can use same format/estructure in a dict

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `(52.51141, 13.30211) in BerlinMap[(BerlinMap['id'] == 404538)].geometry[0]`, since `BerlinMap[(BerlinMap['id'] == 404538)].geometry` is apparently a Series not a DataFrame, and therefore doesn't have any field?